# send (node express) and receive data (reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I trying to get data (zip images) from my node server in my react app

I send my data like that in my node server

```js
router.post('/downloadimages',  function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.Id) {
        download(req.body.Id, (data) => {
            res.status(200).send(data)
        })
    } else {
        res.json({"error": 404})
    }
})
```

And I am get them in my reactjs app like (I use [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) to download) :

```js
import download from 'downloadjs'

getData () {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/downloadimages", {
            "Id": "33",
        })
        .then(data => {
            download(data.data, "test.zip")
        });
    }
```

I can download and open it when I use curl `curl --data "Id=33"  http://localhost:3000/downloadimages --output file.zip` directly on server

But when I use my app, I can't open my archive, I don't know where I did the wrong thing, maybe it's download package in react app ?

Comment: Have you tryed this solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019130/download-save-file-in-react-js

Comment: Yes I tried it, but the result of axios (data) can't be converted to a blob with .blob() I got Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.blob is not a function.
I tried to use new Blob() too, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide what data get back from the fetch?

Comment: In the node server, the download() function returns images in a zip file.
When I fetch it in the web app, I'm trying to get the same zip file

Comment: I see, but  at the error, where  data.blob is not a function, what is the return value?

Comment: downloadId.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.blob is not a function
    at downloadId.js:24
It just crash, and the function doesn't return